# Radio button object doesn't support method checked, but I'm using syntax that has worked before

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I've got a set of radio buttons in a table. I'm trying to have the Crew B radio checked by default.   Among all of my other markup and code, here's what I've got inside the table.  However, I'm getting an "object doesn't support this property or method" on the line where the javascript runs.  Any idea what's going on here?

```
<td width="80px"><input type="radio" name="crew" id="CrewA" value="A">Crew A  </input></td>
<td width="80px"><input type="radio" name="crew" id="CrewB" value="B">Crew B  </input></td>
<td width="80px"><input type="radio" name="crew" id="CrewC" value="C">Crew C  </input></td>
<td width="80px"><input type="radio" name="crew" id="CrewD" value="D">Crew D  </input></td>
<script>document.getElementByID('CrewB').checked = true;</script>
```

.  Here's my script to do that:

Comment: Is this in your code or just a typo? `getElementByID` because it should be `getElementById`

Comment: `document.getElementById`. Javascript is case-sensitive.

Comment: Goodness.  It is a typo. Diodeus gave the correct answer though.

Comment: setting checked to true is 100% valid.

Comment: @epascarello It is valid Javascript, yes, but it's not cross-browser compliant. (IE <= 8 and Safari from memory require checked attributes)

Comment: @RGraham That code works fine in IE7 and IE8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"checked" is not a true/false value. It's a boolean property.

Use:

```
document.getElementById('CrewB').setAttribute('checked', 'checked')
```

Comment: UM, isn't that exactly what the poster has?

Comment: No, I had .checked = true.  .setAttribute('checked','checked') works

Comment: @AlexKibler The answer changed the answer. It used to be exactly what you posted.

Comment: .checked is a boolean property in Javascript, so `.checked = true` should work. Some browsers (Safari, IE) however rely on the existence of the `checked="checked"` attribute in markup and so this answer covers all bases.

Comment: jQuery fixes all this with .prop()

Comment: Why use jQuery to do a simple thing like this...?

Comment: I was not suggesting that. jQuery just fixes all kinds of inconvenient things.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the console you will see the error message: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'getElementByID'`

Look at the code and you will see a classic case of sticky shift key.

```
document.getElementByID('CrewB').checked = true;
                      ^
```

A typo is the error, fix the typo

```
document.getElementById('CrewB').checked = true;
                      ^
```

and the code will work. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5PP2/)

Comment: Good eye on that one!

Answer (score 0):

If crew B is always going to be checked why not just add checked="checked" as an attribute in the HTML so you do not need to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it will be always `checked` by default, you may put it right on its markup, like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="crew" id="CrewB" value="B" checked>Crew B</input>
```